# RegEx find multiple instances of a double letter?

Tags: regex, linux

```
1. 29250X 90 3 ASM123NO48JHF3M344
2. 29250X FD 3 DFWO3957NSTCVIKERH
3. 292505 3R 4 PGHU35N77P10C8WE0W
4. 292505 TH 4 8RJRO239F0117R5MFY
```

I have a text file `codes.txt` full of codes, in the above format. The criteria is that the second column has to have 2 consecutive letters to be extracted; so since (2) has FD and (4) has TH, both lines will be extracted into another file `results.txt`. What RegEx command can I use to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: I have tried `[A-Z][A-Z]{8-9}` but that does not seem to do anything

Comment: What program and what syntax are you using? I know of no program that accepts `[A-Z][A-Z]{8-9}` as a regular expression. Maybe you want to use `perl -ple 'print if / [A-Z][A-Z] /'` ?

Comment: This would have matched two letters followed by '{8-9}'. You might have wanted to use the `{8,9}` quantifier instead ("eight or nine occurences"), but I fail to see how that would have helped you.

Comment: @Corion `grep` (at least with BRE) does, it just interprets `{8-9}` literally

Comment: If you don't want to use perl, `grep ' [A-Z][A-Z] '` would have the same effect as the perl snippet Corion provided. Note that this assume the separators are always spaces rather than tabs and that the second column is the only one that can contain values of exactly 2 characters.

Comment: as the requierement of two letters is on the second column, what about `^[^ ]* [A-Z][A-Z] ` ? is it a space delimited format or fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

I would match as much of the line as you can in order to eliminate false positives.

```
egrep '^[0-9]+\. .{6,} [A-Z]{2} [0-9] .+' codes.txt > results.txt
```

Regex explained:

```
^         Anchor to the beginning of the line
[0-9]+    Match 1 or more numbers
\.        Followed by a period and a space
.{6,}     Followed by at least 6 but maybe more characters and a space
[A-Z]{2}  Followed by 2 Capital letters and a space
[0-9]     Then a digit and a space
.+        Then 1 or more characters
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below may work for you:

codes.txt

```
1. 29250X 90 3 ASM123NO48JHF3M344
2. 29250X FD 3 DFWO3957NSTCVIKERH
3. 292505 3R 4 PGHU35N77P10C8WE0W
4. 292505 TH 4 8RJRO239F0117R5MFY
```

The code:

```
import re

f = open('./codes.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open('./results.txt', 'w')

pa = re.compile(r' [a-zA-Z]{2} ')

for l in lines:
  m = pa.search(l)
  if m and m.group(0):
    f.write(l)
    #print(l, end="")

f.close()
```

The output (in results.txt)

```
2. 29250X FD 3 DFWO3957NSTCVIKERH
4. 292505 TH 4 8RJRO239F0117R5MFY
```